# mathematical biology (steady-states)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

non-dimensionalisation equation:
\begin{equation} \frac {du}{d\tau}=\frac{\overline{\lambda}_{1} u}{u+1} -\overline{r}_{ab}uv -\overline{d}u
\end{equation}
where $\overline{\lambda}_{1}= \frac {\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{2} K_{1}}$
Another non-dimensionalisation equations
\begin{equation} \frac {dv}{d\tau}=v(1-v) -\overline{r}_{ba}uv
\end{equation}
THE REAL QUESTION IS: calculate the steady state $(u_4,v_4)$ and $(u_5,v_5)$? Discuss the occurrence of these steady-states in respect of any relationships between the non-dimensional. Note you are not required to determine the stability of these two states.

=>
I have already calculated the steady-states of $(u_4,v_4)$ and $(u_5,v_5)$ which are

$(u_4,v_4)$ =($ \frac{\overline{\lambda}_{1} - \overline{d} -\overline{r}_{ab}}{\overline{r}_{ab} + \overline{d}} ,1)$

$(u_5,v_5)$ =($ \frac{\overline{\lambda}_{1} - \overline{d} -\overline{r}_{ab}}{\overline{r}_{ab} + \overline{d}}$ ,$ 1 - \overline{r}_{ba} \frac{\overline{\lambda}_{1} - \overline{d} -\overline{r}_{ab}}{\overline{r}_{ab} + \overline{d}}$ )

I HAVE ALREADY CALCULATED $(u_1,v_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2)$ and $(u_3,v_3)$ but i an not interested to talk about their steady-state with respect to non-dimensional parameters.

here are the non-dimensional parameters which I have also determined:

$\overline{\lambda}_{1}= \frac {\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{2} K_{1}}$

$\overline{d}= \frac{d}{\lambda_{2}}$

$\overline{r}_{ab} = \frac{\overline{r}_{ab} K_{2}} {\lambda_{2}}$

$\overline{r}_{ba} = \frac{\overline{r}_{ab} K_{1}} {\lambda_{2}}$

can anyone please please help me in discussion of these steady states $(u_4,v_4)$ and $(u_5,v_5)$ with the above non-dimensional parameters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be? in which case your steady states are mostly wrong, unless im going blind...

\begin{equation} \frac {dv}{d\tau}=v(1-v) -\overline{r}_{ba}uv
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  In a steady state, all derivatives are zero.  That is the definition of a steady state, and it simplifies the equations considerably.

Comment: thanks you your comment. but I knew that already. and that has nothing to do about the discuss of steady-state with the non-dimensional parameters. which I desperately want to know.